# How to disable cloth simulation for performance?

Tags: cloth-simulation, performance

I have a character with a simple cloth sim attached. This causes a lot of slowdown when playing the animation. Simply disabling the realtime display does nothing to improve this. This makes animating the character pretty difficult. Is there a way to temporarily disable the simulation while animating so I can re-enable and simulate it after the fact?

Comment: "Disable in viewports" on the modifier should disable the simulation and give your performance back.  It does in simple tests.  There is something else in your setup, not detailed, that is involved in any remaining slowdown.

Comment: Hm. So, I was using the cloth mesh to drive an armature by using stretch-to constraints. I wrongly assumed the simulation was the problem because there was no slowdown when the cloth modifier was removed completely. Removing the bone constraints seems to have cleared that up. I'll be more thorough next time I post here. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.